# Django. Сортировка по кнопке на странице выдачи результата поиска

Tags: python, queryset

Как в Django сделать кнопки сортировка по дате и по релевантности на странице выдачи поиска.
Есть модель Article, в которой есть поле "publish" - Дата публикации. В классе Meta стоит сортировка по публикации "-publish", т.е. показывать самые свежие упубликованные статьи. Но на странице выдачи поиска я хотел бы сделать кнопку сортировки по датам. На Stackoverflow пользователи советуют передать параметры сортировки методом "GET" в url, что типо такого:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:article_search'%}" class = "#" method="GET">
<select class= "#" name="select">
    <option disabled selected> Способ сортировки</option>
        <option value="v1">Дата публикации: по возрастанию</option>
        <option value="v2">Дата публикации: по убыванию</option>
    </select>
    <button class="#">Применить</button>
</form>
```

Мое представление поиска (views.py):

```
def article_search(request):
form = SearchForm()
query = None
results = []
if 'query' in request.GET:
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        query = form.cleaned_data['query']
        search_vector = SearchVector('title', 'body')
        search_query = SearchQuery(query)
        search_headline = SearchHeadline('body', search_query,
                                         max_fragments=2,
                                         start_sel='<span class="headline">',
                                         stop_sel='</span>')
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            results = Article.published.all().annotate(
                search=search_vector,
                rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
            ).annotate(headline=search_headline).filter(search=search_query).order_by('-rank')
        else:
            results = Article.published.all().annotate(
                search=search_vector,
                rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
            ).annotate(headline=search_headline).filter(search=search_query).order_by('-rank').filter(private=False)

sorting_method = request.GET.get('select')
if sorting_method == 'v1':
    results = Article.published.order_by('publish')
elif sorting_method == 'v2':
    results = Article.published.order_by('-publish')

return render(request,
              'main/search.html',
              {'form': form,
               'query': query,
               'results': results})
```

Но данный способ не работает. Как правильно организовать сортировку в Django по кнопке?

Comment: Во-первых, код должен быть текстом, а не скриншотом. Во-вторых, что означает «не работает», что происходит вместо работы?

Comment: У меня система не пропустила код текстом, рагнулась на табы, хотя они  в PyCharm расставлены верно, за место http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?query=linux, подставляется http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?select=v1. Не очень понятно, как правильно сделать сортивку по кнопке

Comment: <form action="{% url 'main:article_search'%}" class = "#" method="GET">
                        <select class= "#" name="select">
                            <option disabled selected> Способ сортировки</option>
                            <option value="v1">Дата публикации: по возрастанию</option>
                            <option value="v2">Дата публикации: по убыванию</option>
                        </select>
                     <button class="#">Применить</button>
                </form>

Comment: Часть вьюшки:sorting_method = request.GET.get('select')
    if sorting_method == 'v1':
        results = Article.published.order_by('publish')
    elif sorting_method == 'v2':
        results = Article.published.order_by('-publish')

Comment: Также делал по этой рекомендации "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923922/sorting-the-search-result", но тоже не вышло ничего

Comment: Код должен быть в вопросе, а не в комментариях. И что означает "рагнулась на табы", как конкретно рагнулась?

Comment: При сохранении вопроса не удалось сохранить код, было написано "Проверьте табы" или что то в этом роде, хотя табы верно проставлены были. Поэтому сделал скриншотом

Comment: Ну, попробуйте ещё раз и проверьте табы

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, спасибо

Comment: Там опечатка была в слове "ругнулась"

Comment: В показанной вами html-форме нету никакого query, поэтому вполне логично, что в ссылке http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?select=v1 тоже никакой query не появляется

Comment: Не подскажите как передать query?

Comment: не много переписал:                <form method="get" action="{% url 'main:article_search' %}">
                    <a class="filter_by" href="?query={{ query }}&select=v1">По дате(убывание)</a>
                    <a class="filter_by" href="?query={{ query }}&select=v2">По дате(возрастание)</a>
                </form>

Comment: но это выводит все статьи какие есть, как применить именно к результату поиска?

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо за помощь